# is it possible to improve prediction accuracy based on this sample data set?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models

**Question:**
I have a sample dataset that contains a number of features, and a price. I am trying to predict the price. So far my accuracy has been terrible, with a MSE of 350,000 which is huge, relative to the price distribution.

I know its a lot to ask, but as Im in the process of learning machine learning , it could speed my work up greatly or help me avoid wasting time.

- is it worth continuing to refine this or is the feature set too sparse?
- pointer on what to try next.

**Details:**
The dataset is real, but with names masked as i requested by the data owner.
Each row is an accommodation, displaying the number of beds, how energy efficient the accommodation is, overall size, number of bathrooms and the asking price for a set period of time, duration same for all rows.

Locations are set out as Districts. District 1 is broken into the towns in that district, as it is very large. I am doing prediction against District 1 in isolation also, as it may be too different from other districts due to its size.

I initially thought i could use basic regression, but there is no correlation between size, efficiency , beds and price. The only real predictor is the district. On seeing this i tried decision tree & forrest regression, but this did not reduce the MSE very much.

Sincere thanks for any advice.

[Link to DataSet](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgldA0VQfPV9hL9Dc7S-lohJlIldag)

Comment: The variance of the raw price data is 242,000,000,000, so MSE of 350,000 would be impressive.  Surely you mean the root mean squared error?  Using random forest with a 66-34 Training-Test split and the other default setting (in Weka 3.8) I get 231,400 for the root mean squared error.

Comment: But your data are very skewed, with a minimum of 135, a mean of 340,500 and a maximum of 28,000,000.  Those two high observations (price of 28,000,000 and 25,000,000) are more than twice any other observation and aren't really the same thing, I would guess.  But a question: in this data, is this the US system (. is a decimal point) or European (, is a decimal point)?  I'm looking particularly at the size of those two high price observations, which seem small (169 and 177 size, hardly enough for those 10 bathrooms).

Comment: yes, the data is very skewed with a long tail towards the high prices.

Thanks for taking a look. you are correct it is RMSE, typo on my part, apologies.

The price should be a whole number, no commas or decimals. When i view the CSV thats how it shows up.

All other numeric values are decimal, with a period "."

I dont have any further info regarding those entries with a relatively low price for lots of bathrooms so cant provide anymore insight unfortunately.